# Stream chaining in computing a checksum: avoiding memory issues

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, stream, checksum

I have a `FileStream` connected to a xml file that I would like to read directly into a SHA512 object in order to compute a hash for the purposes of a checksum (not a security use).

The issue is twofold:

1. I want to omit some of the nodes in the xml,
2. the file is quite large, and I would rather not load the whole thing into into memory

I can read the whole file into a xml structure, delete the node, then write it to a stream that would then be plugged into `SHA512.ComputeHash`, but that will cause a performance loss. I would prefer to be able to somehow do the deletion of the nodes as an operation on a stream and then chain the streams together somehow into a single stream that can be passed into `SHA512.ComputeHash(Stream)`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How "large" is the source XML?

Comment: Maybe something like this? Read the XML file with an XmlReader, write all wanted nodes to an XmlWriter that writes to a stream that updates the hash.

Comment: @RichardTurner: THe source XML is currently about 30 MB big, but lets assume it could get much larger than that.  And yes, I know this may be micro-optimizing in some situations- please assume I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @dtb: The problem is that according to my understanding, if I write the XMLWriter to a Memory stream, that stream would fill up with the entire file first, and THEN it would get passed to the ComputeHash.  I want the process to act like a pipe, if that makes sense, with some fraction of the xml file in memory at any one time.

Comment: I don't mean writing to a MemoryStream. I mean writing to a Stream that only updates the hash and does not store the bytes.

Comment: @dtb: In principle I like the idea, but I'm not following you on the implementation.  I may be missing something about how the SHA512 works. Could you give an example please?

Comment: You can not only calculate a hash by reading from a Stream. You can also calculate a hash by creating a SHA512 instance and repeatedly updating it with data (TransformBlock, TransformFinalBlock). The CryptoStream class wraps this in a nice package for you. I've posted an example as answer, because it doesn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var hash = new SHA512Cng())
using (var stream = new CryptoStream(Stream.Null, hash, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("input.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // ... write node to writer ...
    }

    writer.Flush();
    stream.FlushFinalBlock();
    var result = hash.Hash;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't seen that method of doing it before.  I will try this out.